# How to scale a number of images to fill area

Tags: css, image, mobile, flexbox

I'm trying to fill an area of web page of a certain, fixed size with an unknown number of images (max 10), maximising the size of the images without overflowing the area. To be mobile friendly, I want it to work both in landscape and portrait mode without needing scrolling.

I've been trying to use flexboxes to have the images wrap, but then they don't scale down and end up overflowing the area. If I use non-wrapping flexboxes, the images scale in landscape mode, but not in portrait. I feel there should be a nice, simple solution to this. Any ideas?

Update:

Here's the essence of the code I've got so far. I've been trying a lot of different things, but this is the cleanest.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
}

.above {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: larger;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

.middle {
 flex-grow: 1;
 max-height: 100%;
}

.below {
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

img {
 border: 5px solid transparent;
 height: 100%;
}

.images {
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 100%;
}

.image {
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="above">
  Some text about the images
 </div>
 <div class="middle">
  <div class="images">
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="below">
  <button>Ok</button>
  <button>Cancel</button>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The point is to try to get the images to stay completely within the div called "middle", but scaled as large as possible. Here are a few wireframes.

Landscape, 10 images:

[image: Landscape, 10 images]

Portrait, 10 images:

[image: Portrait, 10 images]

Portrait, 4 images

[image: Portrait, 4 images]

Comment: Probably a dumb suggestion, but have you tried using `vw` and `vh` for the width and height of your images?

Comment: some code you already developed will be helpful to have an idea of what exactly you need to achieve here. how about the sizes of the images you are talking here? should all the images appear in same size?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Are your image set to responsive (`width: 100%; height: auto`) ? Flexbox works well for these kind of problems

Comment: Does images have equal width and height or every image has own resolutions ? flexbox + vw +vh should do the trick

Comment: Updated the question with code and wireframes. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: I ended up making 2 x 10 different css classes for the images, depending on the amount of images and if landscape or portrait. If only one image, the class will have { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; } in both landscape and portrait mode. If six images, the classes will be { max-width: 30%; max-height: 50%; } and { max-width: 50%; max-height: 30%; } for landscape and portrait respectively, etc. Not the solution I was hoping for, but also not the worst hack possible.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to consider `flex` property here, it's the short hand version of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` properties. See if this is what you're looking for.

```css
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.col{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 1%;
    flex: 1 1 15%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .item {
        height: 100px;
        flex: 1 1 45%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>some text about images</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>Some other elements</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It gave me some thoughts, but in the end, I think your suggestion is missing a few crucial points.

The max-width: 30% in landscape mode would prevent the 2x2 scenario's images from scaling to their max size, and similarly, the fixed height: 150px (and 100px) of the .items would also not allow for, say, a set with a single image to scale up to the full width and height of the container.

It's a hard problem, which is why I had to ask here.

Comment: I used fixed `height` to demonstrate the `flex` behaviors, you can use which ever size you want and it doesn't necessary to fix the `height` at all. `flex` will expand to the size according to the elements inside it.

Comment: By the way I used `margin` property to show the separation of tiles here, since we can not use the exact sizes to `width` and `flex-grow` properties. without `margin` just use the values of 100/(image count). I updated the answer, see if that address to your problems which you comment here

Comment: Yes, flex will expand. But the whole point was to have a maximum size for the area, and have the content of the flexbox shrink instead of overflowing, while still having the images as large as possible.

Comment: is it a fixed size area are we talking about here?

Comment: Yes, it's in the very first sentence of my question.

Comment: So you want to occupy the entire height by the images also, even if there is only one image? may be you should look `object-fit` property there. it can help you to achieve the covering entire area by something inside the `div`